# Orchard CMS 1.7 - Change in header does not appear on the site. Layout.cshtml issue

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.7

I cannot figure out how to change a text in the header section of my site. I am trying to do this in my custom module's theme. This is how my header looks like:

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div id="Logo"><h1><a href="/" title="Go to Home">@WorkContext.CurrentSite.SiteName</a></h1></div>
            <h3>[ We Know Business ]</h3>
            <a class="btn btn-navbar btn-menuh" data-parent="#collapse-nav" data-target=".collapse-menuh">btn</a>
            <a class="btn btn-navbar btn-search" data-parent="#collapse-nav" data-target=".collapse-search">btn</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I changed `[We Know Business]` to `[We know Businesses]` but the updated text is not coming up on any page of my site.

However, my main objective is to use HTML5 and Responsive compatibility in IE8 by injecting conditional CSS and js like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/themes/intrust/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I cannot see the above snippet in "View Source" option.

The reason I changed the text only to check whether I am doing it at the right place or not. When it didn't work I turned Shape Tracing tool on to see what template is being used for the header. But could not highlight any part of the header at all!

Isn't `Layout.cshtml` of my custom theme liable to render the header section? If not, which template I have to look for?

I must be doing something wrong here but cannot figure out what! Please help!

NB: I tried resetting IIS several times but had no luck either.

Comment: Are you sure your theme is selected as the default theme?

Comment: Yes, this is my default theme set from admin

Comment: Where did you put the file?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but what you are looking for is overriding document.cshtml.Orchard has a default in the folder Orchard\src\Orchard.Web\Core\Shapes\Views folder. Copy the file document.cshtml to your theme and put the items that you want in the header section of this document.